# How to combine array with arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need a 5-dimensional data structure in Java with "double" as type for all the cells. For 3 of dimensions I know the size, so it fits to array category. But for 2 of dimensions I don't know the size beforehand; looks like ArrayList. 
I have been able to manage the combination for 3 dimensions in the past:

```
ArrayList(Double)[][] prXifY = (ArrayList(Double)[][]) new ArrayList[m][n];
```

But despite long hours working on it (and through search in the net), I wasn't able to scale it. I need something like this:

```
ArrayList(ArrayList(Double))[][][] prXiXjY = (ArrayList(ArrayList(Double))[][][]) new ArrayList(ArrayList<Double))[m][m][n];
```

When I tried the above code, it says:
"Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList(ArrayList(Double))"

I will appreciate quick and complete answers.

By the way, this is my very first post ever. I tried my best to do a good job on searching beforehand and explaining the problem clearly. Comments on these matters are appreciated as well. :)

Comment: Why are you using parentheses? They aren't the right way to give a generic type argument.

Comment: Specifically, your types should read `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` and not `ArrayList(ArrayList(Double))`.

Comment: I would suggest using Lists all the way down, since generics and arrays don't mix well, but it honestly looks like you should be splitting this up with  a class at some level -- perhaps with a class containing a `List<List<Double>>`, rather than trying to nest five dimensions directly.

Comment: Wow! That was quick. Thanks. First I typed <> signs in the editor here, they didn't appear well in the preview, so I replaced them with (). I didn't do that in my code.

Comment: So I got two suggestions so far: list and split to class. Which one is better for this situation? Can anybody tell me please?

Comment: @Louis Can you explain it to me, please? Do you think that a 3D array with List<List<Double>> as cell-type will work? Then why can't I do that all together?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting writing your own class `TwoDimensionalWhatever`, where `Whatever` is replaced with a description of whatever the meaning of that array is in the actual structure you're building, and having a `List<List<TwoDimensionalWhatever>>`.  It really depends on what dimensions mean what.  Is it actually a three-dimensional array of structures that themselves have two dimensions?  Vice versa?  Is it a one-dimensional array of things that have four dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

An `ArrayList` is an object, and instantiated differently than an array is. In general, to say that you want an ArrayList that holds doubles, you might use something like:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

to specify that you have an ArrayList which holsts ArrayLists which hold doubles...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
```

You see where this is going, I hope.

This just creates the top-level list - it doesn't create any of the cells themselves. For that, you'll need additional `new` statements. This is going to get messy fast, and you may want to stop and consider if there is a better way to store the data than in a 5-dimension array.

Comment: I know. That's why I am asking for other solutions. Do you know how to do the task?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want would look something like this

```
List<List<List<List<List<Double>>>>> myList= new ArrayList<List<List<List<List<Double>>>>> ();
```

as you can tell this looks insane and will be very hard to maintain. You should probably look at alternative methods of doing this.

Comment: I am asking about those alternative methods. Do you know one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Multi dimensional arrays can be created like so:

```
    ArrayList<Double> oneDimensionalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> twoDimensionalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> threeDimensionalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>>> fourDimensionalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>>>> fiveDimensionalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I would definitely recommend considering whether a 5 dimensional array is what you require for the problem at hand; it smells like something is wrong

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I am implementing an algorithm for multidimensional object. It is very common in scientific problems. Seems like it is not easy to do that efficiently though. Because nobody has a solution/alternative to this problem, I am going to share with everybody how I got around it.
because the size of those two dimensions are in a short range, I decided to go with  5-dim arrays and use the max possible size for those 2 dimensions. Please, stop posting that it is not the best way to do that, give me some good ideas that I don't have already. I will appreciate that.